# Breaking Bad S4E10 "Salud" Walter Jr's jacket

Tags: breaking-bad

At the beginning of episode 10 of season 4 Walter Jr was shown a surprise birthday present. He was wearing an orange jacket.

Is it an *Aperture Science* Jacket from the game *Portal/Portal 2*?

Image of jacket blow (Because of Netflix privacy I can't take screen shot so took a pic of screen instead)

[image: Aperture science?]
[image: Aperture science logo]

Comment: Do you have a picture?

Answer (score 2):

No.  There's no logo on the back like the Aperture Science jacket has.  It's just a standard orange sweatjacket.

Closeup of the logo from Breaking Bad:
[image]

Still looks like 2 circular arrows to me.

Comment: Yes but on the front there is a white logo that looks like aperture science logo

Comment: I've got it on my TV screen now.  Looks more like a Warner Brothers logo than an Aperture Science logo.  Besides, the Aperture suits have a white rectangular patch.  Walt Jr's jacket definitely doesn't have that.

Comment: You may be right after studying it for a while. It's crazy cause they make that same orange jacket tho.

Comment: To me, on my TV screen, that circle looks like 2 arrows.  I can't find any apparel company with a logo like that.  Then again, I can't find any warm up jackets that look like that at all, so I can't confirm exactly what it is.  But it's definitely not an Aperture Science jacket.

Comment: Look at my image that I posted.

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: Nah. There more then two splits in the circle.

Comment: I also watched it just now, in HD. It's **not** two arrows but a white hexagon with 6 slits (it's almost like a little sun symbol), kinda like [this](http://www.letterlogos.com/letter-v-logos/letter-v-logo2.gif). 100%. If it's not the logo from Portal, it sure looks like an attempt to *resemble* it. You can see it upclose when Flynn visits Walter later on.

Comment: Agreed, Walt.  My eyes are a little shot, but it does look like 6 slits.